# Inserts an element into an array and returning the index reallocating the array in case of full array

Tags: java, arrays, insert, indexing

I need to implement a method **public int insert (int x)** which inserts x in the "elements" array keeping it ordered, and returns the index to which it is entered; 
if the element is already present, don't insert x and returns -1; if the array is full, it reallocates "elements" array in an array of double size and then insert the item x. 
I know that there are probably similar methods already in the API but rather implement it.

I wrote this, but I do not know how to complete it...

```
public int insert(int x)  {
    if(numElements == elements.length) {
                //code
            }   
    int pos = binarySearch(x);
    if(pos != -1) 
        return -1;
    if(elements[-(pos + 1)] != null) {
        for(int i = numElements; i >= -(pos + 1); i--)
            elements[i + 1] = elements[i];
    }
    elements[-(pos + 1)] = x;
    numElements++;
    return -(pos + 1);
}
```

I do not know if what I wrote is correct, however, and I miss the case of a full array. Can anyone help me?
Thanks

---

```
private int binarySearch(int x) {
    int inf = 0;
    int sup = numElements - 1;
    if(sup == -1 || elements[0] > x)
        return -1;
    if(elements[sup] < x)
        return -(numElements + 1);
    //Invariante di ciclo: se x in a, allora x in a[inf...sup]
    while(inf <= sup) {
        int i = (inf  + sup) >>> 1; //divide per due
        if(elements[i] > x)
            sup = i - 1;
        else if(elements[i] < x)
            inf = i + 1;
        else
            return i;
    }
    return -(inf + 1);
}
```

Comment: You need to reallocate `elements` and use `System.arraycopy` to copy the elements over to the new array. Don't forget the case where the array shrinks too.

Comment: Are you using "-(pos + 1)" instead "0"? pos will be -1, so it could be simpler if you write elements[0] if i understand it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

What I did was create a new array that is twice the size and then use the `System.arraycopy` to move the existing elements. Lastly I assigned the reference of the enlarged array to the `elements` variable.

I used `System.arraycopy` because it is faster than a manually made loop-copy. It is using a native implementation by the JVM.

Also i replaced the check for array displacement and the for loop with `System.arraycopy`.
Also, the -(pos  + 1) gives you a negative number.

```
public int insert(int x)  {
    if(numElements == elements.length) {
         int[] enlargedElements = new int[elements.length * 2];
         System.arraycopy(elements, 0, enlargedElements, 0, elements.length);
         elements = enlargedElements;
    }   
    int pos = binarySearch(x);
    if(pos == -1) 
        return -1;
    if(pos < numElements) {
        System.arraycopy(elements, pos, elements, pos + 1, numElements - pos);
    }
    elements[pos] = x;
    numElements++;
    return pos;
}

private int binarySearch(int x) {
    int inf = 0;
    int sup = numElements - 1;
    if(sup == -1 || elements[0] > x)
        return 0;
    if(elements[sup] < x)
        return numElements;
    //Invariante di ciclo: se x in a, allora x in a[inf...sup]
    while(inf <= sup) {
        int i = (inf  + sup) >>> 1; //divide per due
        if(elements[i] > x)
            sup = i - 1;
        else if(elements[i] < x)
            inf = i + 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
    return inf;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but doesn't work. When I create an array of length 4 and I insert 2, it is inserted in position 0 (OK), and then I insert 1 that is placed in position 0 (OK), and then when I insert 2 is launched a ArrayInxexOutOfBoundsException. Why?

Comment: Does `binarySearch` return the position where it should be inserted if it is not found and -1 if it is found ? Right ?

Comment: @ Andrei no, does not work. When I enter a number into an empty array it always returns -1. This thing is correct because it runs binarySearch that returns -1 if the element sought is not present in the array (empty array)...

Comment: Thank you for your patience. There is another problem. 
I create an array of length 4. 
I insert the value 2 -> [2, /, /, /] 
I insert the value 3 -> [2, 3, /, /] 
The insert the value 1 -> [1, 2, 0, /] 

The program has a problem with the inclusion of the number 1...

Comment: Try now. It was not copying the last element.